# Running Mantis on MS SQL Server

Tags: php, mantis

As a part of the technology standardization in the organization I work at, we're moving from MySQL and Linux to MS SQL Server and Windows. One of the PHP-based applications that we use is Mantis, a bug tracking system available at http://www.mantisbt.org

Has anyone had any luck getting Mantis to work completely with MS SQL Server? I've got Mantis 1.1.8 working for the most part but file attachments do not work, while Mantis 1.2.1 does not install on MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a step by step guide, maybe this helps out: http://gonfva.blogspot.com/2010/03/mantis-on-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

The mantis page states:

> It is written in the PHP scripting language and works with MySQL, MS SQL, and PostgreSQL databases and a webserver.

So it is possible, and you might want to use the official mantis support channels.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm also that Mantis 1.2.x does **not** install on MS SQL Server. We tried at work but had to move to a LAMP stack to get 1.2.x running. Seems to work with 1.1.x versions.

Also see this forum thread: http://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18827

Answer (score 0):

As part of the MantisBT development team I can tell you that although there is code support for MS SQL Server, there are many issues with it. The cause of the problem is that none of the developers - or contributing users - are running an SQL Server installation and we're not aware of any free setups which we can use to the SQL Server.

Long story short: it probably doesn't work out of the box, but you might force it into running by patching it. If you do, please contribute those changes back, as there are many users which reported problems with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that Mantis 1.2.6 **IS** successfully installable and usable on IIS 7.5 + PHP 5.3.6 
Tips: http://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/2011/03/setting-up-mantisbt-on-iis-7-w-sql-server/